# where in the apple API is the variable "bounds.minX", "bounds.maxX" defined?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, bounds

I was just wondering where in the apple API is the variable "bounds.minX", "bounds.maxX" defined? I have looked at "UIView" and "CGRect" documentation but couldn't seem to find it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's covered in the "new" reference. Apple likes to break all documentation links and reduce the usefulness of their documentation every few years, and this is one of those years.

https://developer.apple.com/reference/coregraphics/cgrect

Comment: awesome! Thank you so much!